# Winphone to WCF Encryption

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, encryption

I'm working on a university project that requires encrypted data to be sent from a Windows Phone to a WCF service.  I have control over both sides.

I know next to nothing about encryption and wondered what the best way to encrypt simple string data would be between the client and server?  If it makes any difference, the WCF endpoint is using HTTP.

Does anybody have any good recommendations for a starting point?

Comment: Can you simply replace http with https?

Comment: Would I not then have to have a certificate?

Comment: It's probably possible to use a self signed certificate. You probably need to add your own certificate verification though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the following links

1. [Transport Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733043.aspx)
2. [Message Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx)
3. [Implementing Transport and Message Layer Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480582.aspx)

Broadly speaking, #1 and #2 indicate two different ways to secure communications with a WCF endpoint. #1 uses HTTPS bindings to secure the transport channel, while #2 involves encrypting and/or signing the actual messages (either the whole message, or parts of it). Depending on your requirements, you might need either #1  or a combination of #1 and #2. Transport Security is by far the simplest option, and good enough for most use cases.

Answer (score 1):

use HTTPS - the protocol itself is available in the framework.

you would need a certificate on the server-side (WCF endpoint) - though you can [create one yourself](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate.html), which is called a "self-signed" certificate. this is NOT recommended for any "production" use but just for testing purposes.

To make that work you would need to disable some failsafes (which reject such certificates by default) - for some code see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7148509/847363).

IF you need an "official" certificate then you can obtain one for a domain you control for free [here](http://cert.startcom.org/). Although I strongly recommend to buy one from some bigger CA (like Thawte, Verisign etc.) !